# Function to return value of cookie

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, cookies, firebase-authentication

This is the Code I use to create my cookie

```js
 document.cookie = (firebase.auth().currentUser.phoneNumber);
    handleSignedInUser(user);
```

This is the code I use to read the value of my cookie and assign its value to a google map marker label

```js
var markerLabel = document.cookie;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: data.User.l[0],
      lng: data.User.l[1]
      
    },
    map: map,
    label: markerLabel
  });
```

[Picture of Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afd2Q.png)
Instead of only displaying the phone number it also says phone number undefined. Another stack overflow user mentioned that Im not returning the value of the cookie correctly.
I found this function for returning the value of a cookie on https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

```js
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to apply this function to my code. If anyone could help me with this I would really appreciate it

Comment: Use setCookie function first to set cookie with proper name. Then access it with getCookie.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set cookie properly with a name so that you can read it by name later. Where ever you found `getCookie` function, there should be an opposite one, something like `setCookie` which you should use to set cookie. So you workflow will be like this:

```
setCookie('phoneNumber', firebase.auth().currentUser.phoneNumber);
```

Then

```
var markerLabel = getCookie('phoneNumber');
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {
    lat: data.User.l[0],
    lng: data.User.l[1]
  },
  map: map,
  label: markerLabel
});
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: setCookie is not defined
    at signInSuccess (auth.js:11)
    at xk (firebaseui.js:291)
    at wk (firebaseui.js:289)
    at firebaseui.js:323

Comment: Of course it's not defined, as I said in my answer, you need to include it first same you did for getCookie.

Comment: so should I make my document.cookie = setCookie('phoneNumber', firebase.auth().currentUser.phoneNumber);

Comment: No, you should add `setCookie` function same you did for getCookie. And set cookie `setCookie('phoneNumber', firebase.auth().currentUser.phoneNumber);`. Don't touch `document.cookie` manually.

Comment: I don't have a get cookie function in my code. The code that I posted was a function I found online but I'm not sure how to implement it

Comment: One more time: if you want to use getCookie function, you need to include it into your project. Similarly you need setCookie to be included either. So take those two functions from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie and use in your code.